# How to get specific properties from a list based on another list which contains properties name

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

It could be basic concept but i am not able to make it happen.

```
public class ClassA
{

    public String firstName { get; set; }
    public String lastName { get; set; }
    public int employeeID{ get; set; }
    public decimal salary { get; set; }
}

data in List A = List<ClassA> :

 firstName | lastName |employeeID | salary
 John      | Smith    | 123       |$400
 Emila     | Johnson  | 124       |$500
```

I want to select few properties from List A based on the data in List B.

```
public class ClassB
{

    public String column{ get; set; }
    public String coulmnName{ get; set; }
}

data in List B  = List<ClassB> 

     column   | coulmnName
    firstName | First Name
    lastName  | Last Name
```

So Finally by using List A and List B (I need properties which exist in List B and i need to change property name as columnName of List B.)

```
Final data:

 First Name | Last Name 
 John       | Smith
 Emila      | Johnson
```

Comment: You might be able to solve it more easily if you convert the first List (of details) into a datatable and then just filter it...almost like you would do in a database.

Comment: Do you work with collections, such as `List<ListA>` ? It looks like it...

Comment: @MichałTurczyn yes this us the way i will update where required.

Comment: So please make your question more clearer, names of your classes are misleading...

Comment: @MichałTurczyn updated. Please let me know if this is clear now.

Comment: It's better now :)

Answer (score 0):

Trying to use linq would be tricky since you do not know all the property that you would be selecting at compile time.

A workaround would be to capture all the properties in a 2-D array:

```
public class Item
{
    public String firstName { get; set; }
    public String lastName { get; set; }
    public int employeeID { get; set; }
    public decimal salary { get; set; }
}

public class Filter
{
    public String PropertyName { get; set; }
    public String PropertyValue { get; set; }
}

private string GetPropertyValue(Item item, string propertyName)
{
    return item.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(item, null).ToString();
}
```

And the actual code would be:

```
            List<Item> items = new List<Item>();
            items = CreateData(items); // fill with dummy items
            List<Filter> filters = new List<Filter>();
            filters = CreateFilter(filters); // fill with dummy items
            string[,] target = new string[items.Count,filters.Count];

            int row = 0, col = 0;
            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                foreach (var filter in filters)
                {
                    target[row, col] = GetPropertyValue(item, filter.PropertyName);
                    row++;
                }
                row = 0;
                col++;

            }
```

You can store the type information about individual properties as well, but doing anything with anonymous types where you do not have the structure at compile time will be quite tricky.

Comment: Have you consider property Name change as well?

Comment: Nopes, well I assume by property name change you mean the header row. You can add that yourself before you begin the loop. Take care of the 2D array length in that case